# OpenLayers 3 change point fill color depending on feature parameter value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, openlayers-3

I'm populating my map with geojson and all my points have a feature parameter with a specific numeric value. It's a map with temperature values.

Each of this points will need a different fill color depending on the value.

I'm looking for ways to improve my code here. The return value will create the fill color of each point:

```
 var tempVal = feature.get('tempertaure_value');
 var tempNum = Number(tempVal.toFixed());

switch (true) {
    case tempNum == -30:
        return '#0e0e15';
        break;
    case tempNum == -29:
        return '#0d131f';
        break;
    case tempNum == -28:
        return '#0e1226';
        break;
     ... etc ...
    }
```

Can I create a multidimensional array that loops for a key value and returns the color value?

I would appreciate help for a better solution that what I currently have  because my switch statement has become massive, up to 81 temperature values (from -30 to 50 degrees).

Comment: Would you like specific colors or random ones?

Comment: Specific colors. Ideally I could make this array flexible so that I could change the values if a new map layer filter is implemented (rainffall rate points) with it's custom colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create an object like:

```
var colors = {
  '-30': '#0e0e15',
  '-29': '...',
  '-28': '...'
};
```

To access:

```
// just supposing here
var tempVal = feature.get('tempertaure_value');
var color = colors[tempVal];
```

Comment: How do I access it?

`return color[tempVal]`

I'm not retrieving any data

Comment: `var color = colors[tempVal];`! I'm using `feature` reference from your question.

Comment: `return` from what? You didn't show enough code. Try to console some info: `console.log(tempVal)`; `console.log(color[tempVal])`;

Comment: I had missed a value in the array and it was throwing an error. I've resolved this now and works a treat! Cheers @JonatasWalker

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Chroma.js](http://gka.github.io/chroma.js). You pass the needed colors into the `range` method and their respective values to the `domain` method:

```
var scale = chroma.scale(['blue', 'yellow', 'red']).domain([-30, 10 , 50]);
```

It returns a method you can use to return a color based on the value you pass as the parameter:

```
scale(-30).hex(); // returns hex code for blue
scale(10).hex();  // returns hex code for yellow
scale(30).hex();  // returns hex code for orange
scale(50).hex();  // returns hex code for red
```

Here's an example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/k5HPfi?p=preview

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look into this